# Extract substrings from a string in flutter using regex

Tags: arrays, string, flutter, dart

I want to extract sub strings from a string using regex in flutter.

Eg: if string is `"HI hello @shemeer how are you @nijin"`, the expected result will be  `[shemeer,nijin]`

Input : `String s= "HI hello @shemeer ul haq how are you @nijinsha rah"`

Output: `output=["shemeer ul haq","nijinsha rah"]`

Is anybody knows it, please help me

Comment: you should call [allMatches](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Pattern/allMatches.html) method, all you need is to write a valid `RegExp` - there is a lot of online tutorials on how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string into words and then look for `@` and generate list based on it.

```dart
    final names = data
        .split(" ")
        .where((element) => element.startsWith("@"))
        .map((e) => e.substring(1))
        .toList();
```

Or use `allMatches` with `RegExp(r'@\w+')` as pskink mentioned on comment.

```dart
final names = RegExp(r'@\w+')
    .allMatches(data)
    .map((e) => e.group(0)!.substring(1))
    .toList();
```

Comment: hope you got it

Comment: I was updated the query, please check and reply

Comment: You can ask new  question while it is  different from previous one. And while name words length can be different, I don't know about this regex.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use this regex pattern: `(?<=@)\w+`

```
RegExp exp = RegExp(r'(?<=@)(\w+)');
String str = 'HI hello @shemeer how are you @nijin';
Iterable<RegExpMatch> output = exp.allMatches(str);
for (final m in output) {
  print(m[0]);
}
```